# How to add image slider in email newsletter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, newsletter

I have been created email newsletter using [***mailchimp***](http://mailchimp.com/)

Now i want to add image slider with responsive design,

But i have been searched lot online..

Some online docs says can't able to add image slider in email newsletter.

For example this [link](http://wowslider.com/rq/add-scroller-jquery-in-an-email-newsletter-ce.html) told., its impossible.

So, may i know, what is the exact link, to achieve this one?

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imageslider would need a JS running, having inline js in the email is not possible because the email will be blocked by most email providers.

Comment: no I don't think there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unfortunately you cannot do it. Neither CSS3 sliders nor JS sliders will work in HTML email.

## NO-JS in Email newsletter. Proof?

Inside the `<head>` of your email newsletter simply insert:

```
<script>alert("JS WORKS! ...not");</script>
```

Sent that email - and that's your **proof that Email Clients do not support JS**

---

## GIF animated image

[image]

You could eventually go wit ha **.gif animation**. Will not work in **Outlook 2007** - but at least it'll show the first frame.
Don't exagerate with the .gif animations, since the more frames you use that bigger your **file size**.
Also don't forget that you're **limited with the color palette** (256) so think twice:

**You don't want the user to wait for 900KB .gif image.**

---

## JPG Static image

[image]
**My suggestion** is to create a calling and beautiful **Slider-alike .jpg image**.
**Link it** to your site where you present your products.

```
<a href="http://example.com/products"><img src="http://example.com/nl/img/img.jpg"></a>
```

This appealing image has just **45KB**. Every Email Client will be happy to serve such image without blacklisting you.
Also, see your MailChimp **Click-trough rate**. Should lead to surprising results!

Comment: @sandhu you can easily create in a couple of minutes in photoshop a .gif image that acts like a slider gallery :)

Comment: @sandhu you don't need a doc proof. Create an email that has simply `<script>alert("Hello Proof!")</script>` in the `<head>` of your document. It'll not run, youll never see that Alert! Cause JS will not run on email clients. So JS galleries will not run either. Hope that was enough of a proof.  You can mention that in your report. CSS3 support is limited. So you cannot achieve galleries using CSS3 `transition` either.

Comment: @sandhu explain what? How to make a .gif animation? It's everything in my answer (I've edited it since my first post). Read it.

Comment: @sandhu a static **non-animated** .jpg image that looks like a slider! With left right buttons, a call-to-action button... so basically a static image that looks like a slider. The user will try to click it - and it will be redirected to your website.

Comment: @sandhu https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/ Use Google. Campaign Monitor has done an astonishing job at answering all kind of Email Newsletter questions. They provide all the info you'll ever need.

Comment: @sandhu that *english* on that page is just showing you in what email clients the iframe will work. Not in many so DON'T USE IFRAME!

Comment: @sandhu you *can* use iframe, but most Mail Clients won't show it. So use it *if you're really told to do so*.

Answer (score 2):

Imageslider would need a JS running, having inline js in the email is not possible because the email will be blocked by most email providers.

However you can use a GIF image: https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-animated-gifs-in-email

Comment: @sandhu you can't add an image slider to an email. Gif images is the best alternative you have.

Comment: Have multiple images appear after one another

Comment: depends on what you mean by "move"

Comment: @sandhu No gif image is not a slider. if you take a look at the link I gave you you'd understand what a gif image is, there's an example of it that you'll find if you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

So javascript is not possible in emails like others have stated above. There are so many security reason for this...

That being said you definitely CAN implement as image slider or more accurately an image carousel with pure html and css using checkbox/radio hacks. The support however isn't just limited to email clients but more significantly is limited by email services like mailchimp which do support sending emails because mailchimp [Form elements including checkbox, radio and labels are stripped from emails...](http://freshinbox.com/resources/esp-support.php)

That being said here is an example:

http://freshinbox.com/resources/tools/carousel/